# Display username jsondata in every View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, global-variables

1. I currently working on an IOS application using Objective-C. The problem that I encounter is, I need to display the username from the jsondata in every view controller. (something like facebook, when you've logged in, your full name / username will display on) [image]
2. I'm using sbjson v3.1.1 framework from [Github](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/downloads) to perform user authentication in my application . How do I call the username data from jsondata ?  (I have 1,userid, password and username in my jsondata array)

3.Here is my Authentication code.

```
@try {

    if([[txtLogin text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
        [self alertStatus:@"Please enter both Username and Password" :@"Login Failed!"];
    } else {
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"userid=%@&pass=%@",[txtLogin text],[txtPassword text]];
        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.14:8888/itrack/mobile/login.php?"];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
        if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
        {
            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

            SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
            NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
            NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
            NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"login"] integerValue];
            NSLog(@"%d",success);

          //  NSString *test = (NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"username"];


            if(success == 1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                [self alertStatus:@"Logged in Successfully." :@"Login Success!"];

                homepageVC *controller = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeEN"];
                [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

                //redirect to homepage
               // UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"main" bundle:nil];
                //UIViewController *newView = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
                //[self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];


            } else {

                NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"err"];
                [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Login Failed!"];
            }

        } else {
            if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Login Failed!"];
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    [self alertStatus:@"Login Failed." :@"Login Failed!"];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways you can do it is store username in the `NSUserDefaults` and then retrieve in every other view controller.  This way if username key is not nil then you know that user did authenticate.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:"TheName" forKey:@"username"];
// you can store any other properties if neeeded
[defaults synchronize]; // to save the data into NSUserDefaults
```

to retrieve the username in any other view controller even if the app was restarted you would

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *userName = [defaults objectForKey:@"userName"];
```

Let me know if that works in your case.

Comment: I've tried your code, but my label's text become empty now. I think your code is working,just maybe my syntax is wrong.

Comment: `- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *userName = [defaults objectForKey:@"userName"];
  //  NSLog(userName);
    
    usernamelabel.text = userName;` 
This viewdidload is from my homepage.

Comment: Make sure you syncronize and if you can post the code where you set the label.

Comment: Did the user already logged in?  Is the username key is set in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: I just put [defaults synchronize]; in my homepage viewdidload ?

Comment: @ChiYang you would use [defaults syncronize]; only when you add/store something new in the defaults

Comment: yes, user already logged in. is this way correct ?
`NSUserDefaults *test1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [test1 setObject:@"sample" forKey:@"username"];
                 [test1 synchronize];`

Comment: @ChiYang yes that's correct.  Are you able to make it work.

Comment: Yes it's work, now i can use the variable in any View Controller. @yan

Comment: That's great!  Just wanted to add if you the user logs off you can remove the data from NSUserDefaults by [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"username"]; and then synchronize.  Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you for your advise. Really appreciate ~ @yan